# What screwdriver I should use for this screw head?

Tags: faucet, screws, screwdriver

I am trying to unscrew the screw head you see in the picture.  It is from the kitchen faucet handle.

From looking online, it is usually a hex screw head. I tried a hex-key wrench, it didn't work, and tried every tool I have that could fit with no luck.

I am clueless, which one to use. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image: Faucet handle screw head]

Comment: can you post a clearer picture?

Comment: It is so small it is hard to get a clear picture. I took some pictures this is the clearest one, unfortunately.

Comment: That looks like it used to need an Allen key (it was a hexagonal hole into which a hexagonal rod fitted) but it's been rounded, possibly by using the wrong size Allen key and now there isn't enough left to find any purchase. I think you're going to need more than a screwdriver; I know there are devices which will help but I'm not knowledgeable enough to provide the advice you'll need. I don't think it's going to be easy, and you'll probably have to replace that screw when you've finished.

Comment: Thank Andrew, for your feedback! 
A device that removes the screw is a good idea; I will definitely look into it.

Comment: A problem with this picture is that, like craters on the moon, iit could be interpreted as convex or concave. If concave then it would need an Allen key. If convex, it requires a spanner/wrench. Can you clarify?  Are we looking at a bump or a hole?

Comment: In similar situation, I've hammered a flat head screwdriver into the hole.  If its sized right, it'll engage enough to get the screw out.   Might be the end of the screwdriver

Comment: @KyleB - it would be the end of the screwdriver. Nothing alse would fit..!

Comment: Flat screwdrivers are easily repaired with a grinding wheel. That's a good strategy.

Comment: Plenty of good suggestions below, but one other thing. It looks like there is some crud in socket which should be removed before trying the torc/Allen key.

Answer (score 33):

It appears that the hex sides of that screw head have been rounded off due to the use of an ill-fitting hex wrench. A metric and an SAE hex wrench will both fit in there, but the use of the wrong one, while it *feels* like it fits properly, can be *just* loose enough that if the set screw is corroded in a bit, the wrench can slip and round over the edges.

You will need a screw extractor, like this:

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of Lowes.com. No endorsement of brand or vendor intended or implied.</sup>

You insert this into a drill and run the drill in reverse. The extractor has a reverse thread that drills into the head of the screw and also turns the screw to back it out.

For the small added expense (and probably near impossibility of finding them individually), I'd suggest that you purchase a set of 3-5 extractors. That will help ensure you have the proper size for *this* screw, and you'll have a variety for future use. Note that these should work on nearly any screw with any type of screw head - slotted, Phillips, Torx, or other - not just the hex head of your set screw.

Once you have it out, you'll need to take it back to the hardware store/home-improvement center to buy an exact match (thread & length) replacement. As much work as you put into getting it out, you don't want to reinsert it and have to do it again...

Comment: The extractors I've used have all been quite brittle. I'd be reluctant to start one using a drill -- how about a tap handle instead? The extractors are square at the end just like taps, after all! Also, if the hole in the screw isn't deep enough to accept an extractor, use a _left-handed_ drill bit to drill the hole deeper. Half the time I find the left-hand drill bit winds the screw out and I don't even need the extractor.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't be using a drill, except on very, very slow! If they were meant for that, they would not have a square drive. That's for the same use as a tap.

Comment: A tap handle would work, I'm sure. _I_ don't happen to have one, and the particular set of screw extractors I've got have hex ends and the instructions explicitly state to use them in a drill, but to run the drill _very_ slowly in reverse. I support the proper response is to "follow the instructions".

Comment: If this is a hex head screw it's at a severe angle to the opening in the surface. I see the optical illusion and don't think it is.

Comment: I said "hex head" in response to one of the comments that identified it as such, and based on my experience of only seeing hex heads in set screws. A screw extractor would work no matter what type of head the screw originally had, though, so it's of minimal importance to my answer.

Comment: Huh... random drive-by down vote. I wonder why... "Screw extractor" would be the standard answer to "how do I extract a screw". There are some excellent alternatives proposed in the other answers. Wonder what I did to make someone mad...

Answer (score 27):

I mostly agree with FreeMan, but I think this was originally a Torx (six-pointed star) drive. The corners look deeper than I'd expect from an Allen drive.

I would get a set of Torx bits and look for the largest one that fits (which is the correct size for *any* screw head). Gently tap it in with a hammer, then attach the screwdriver or ratchet handle. While keeping the bit in line with the screw and pressed in tightly, see if you can turn it.

Once it's out, replace it.

[image]

Comment: That photo is what a Torx head looks like after it's been abused by a hex driver.  It's all rounded except for the deepest part of the lobes.

Comment: I agree. There's other weird splined heads but they're used by hardly anybody except Apple.

Comment: Yeah. This is what I thought when I looked at this yesterday, but I got sidetracked and didn't answer. I like the idea of tapping in an oversized bit.

Comment: I didn't say "oversized", I said the largest that fits. That would be the _correct_ size.

Comment: The _correct_ size would simply spin in the head, since there's likely not enough left for the bit to grab on to, since, presumably, the _correct_ size was used and ended up stripping out the head, leaving what we see here. No?

Comment: I don't think so. Like SiHa said, someone has used the wrong bit here and boogered things up. I think the _right_ bit will still hold if used properly.

Comment: Valid point. Upon closer inspection, I do see the remnants of a couple of little rounds that could be for a Torx bit. If it's not _too_ tight, there may be enough purchase to get the screw loose. In _general_, though, my statement would stand.

Comment: Oversized bits generally won't fit without tremendous force, which deforms the remaining metal substantially. You wouldn't pound like that on a faucet you intend to repair.

Comment: Yeah, apologies. The *correct* size. And when that slips, an oversized one ;)

Answer (score 12):

Find the largest allen or torx wrench or bit that is small enough to fit in the rounded-off hole. Mix up some 5-minute epoxy or epoxy putty, and put a blob of it into the hole. Immediately insert the allen or torx into the epoxied hole and let it harden for 24 hours. You now have a perfect allen or torx cavity with a tool in it. Unscrew carefully. Replace screw with a new one.

Comment: Would this also work for a phillips/star screw that has been stripped? I have a similar problem but I'd be concerned the area for the epoxy isn't large enough to be strong enough to turn once cured.

Comment: Yes, it would. In fact, it will have a better hold on the screw head due to the more pronounced shape.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Of course, it requires a sacrificial tool, since the epoxy probably won't come off cleanly enough to reuse the tool. Also, be aware that a standard, 90° bent hex key will only spin 180° (or so, but likely less than 360°) before hitting a wall or possibly the faucet (in this case), so you won't get it unscrewed very far before being stuck again. If you use a hex bit that can be connected to a drill, ratchet, or wrench, they you should be good to go.

Comment: Agreed, excellent answer.  If this is a one-off, a sacrificial screw bit is almost certainly cheaper than buying a screw extractor set.  +1

Comment: @FreeMan Assuming a typical L-shaped hex key, just insert the long arm of the L into the hole and use the short arm for turning. That should give you plenty of leverage to loosen the set screw, and if it doesn't, just grip the short arm using your favourite tool and try again. Yes, you'll likely twist the key beyond repair, but that doesn't matter here. A perfect candidate for a sacrificial hex key is the super cheap kind bundled with Ikea furniture and the like. Those are made of such a soft metal that you can hammer them into not-exactly fitting holes and get extra purchase that way.

Comment: @TooTea that _could_ work, but it may not. It depends on the proximity to the wall, faucet handles/spout. I mention it as something to consider before applying epoxy and discovering a major "oops"...

Answer (score 1):

Giving a cheaper option, maybe you can **try to cut a line** with a rotary tool and simply **use a flat screwdriver**

[image]
[image]

[Example GIF](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/evmxfnqpx0j0llkqhpev.mp4)

Comment: While this is a good suggestion in general, I don't see how it could work in this particular situation. The screw head is buried in a small access hole in the handle, you would have an extremely hard time getting a rotary tool in without damaging the handle.

Comment: Yeah, that could be quite hard, though. It's just an idea. Maybe the rotary tool it's not strictly required, but any other methods could be as hard as this one.
I was thinking if the screw extractor can fit, maybe this solution could too, but being  less expensive...

Comment: Agree. This is an excellent technique on the conveniently raised sample screw, but would be nearly impossible to apply to the OPs set screw.

Comment: ̶n̶e̶a̶r̶l̶y̶  impossible :)